# Add a sink, shorten a table

Tags: laundry

I have bought a narrow table made of strong wood.  Now I want to put a sink in it, and to make it shorter in length.  How should I do this?

Comment: Pictures (especially the underside) and dimensions (before and after) please. Also, can you tell us about your level of DIY inclination and tools you have at your disposal?

Comment: Call a cabinet maker.